# Overriding UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I am trying to override a method in the uitextview class and i want to do it in the class i am working in but i can't get it to work. I have only seen people override it in a separate class. Thank You.

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyTextView : UITextView

@end
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyTextView * tv;

@end





//////////////////////////////////





   #import "ViewController.h"



@implementation MyTextView

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender    
{    
    [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;  //do not display the menu
   // [self resignFirstResponder];                      //do not allow the user to selected anything
    return NO;
}

@end


@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tv;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tv = [[MyTextView alloc] init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
-(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(MyTextView *)textView
{
    NSRange range = textView.selectedRange;
    if(range.location<textView.text.length)
    {
        NSString * getRidOfFirstHalfString = [tv.text substringFromIndex:range.location];
        NSString * selectedString = [getRidOfFirstHalfString substringToIndex:range.length];


        NSLog(@"%@",selectedString);

    }
    else
    {
        // Do what ever you want to do

    }   
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in the top of your class:

```
@interface MyTextView : UITextView

@end

@implementation MyTextView

- (xxx)overRidedMethod
{
    // do something
}

@end

... your class
{
    MyTextView *foo = [MyTextView alloc] init.....]
```

Comment: if you put the outlet in your implementation file, then I believe IB will see the UITextView subclass. So in IB you will drag in a UITextView into the the canvas. You will then need to change its class to MyTextView. Then you can make an outlet etc.

Comment: ok that works now but i am getting an error. do u know y? Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString substringFromIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'

Comment: Well you have some other problem dealing with strings - good luck! At least you got what you asked for - how to subclass UITextView

Comment: can u also address this? it wasn't happening before.

Comment: Your code in textViewDidChangeSelection: is fraught with problems. What if he range length is 0 or the range.location is NSNotFound? You need to add NSLog messages around all those lines (as the rest of us do) also enable lldb and enable exceptions in Xcode so the debugger will show you the line that is causing the exception. Everyone who is doing serious iOS development has to learn how to do this.